# Random lighting for 18 pin LED

Tags: led

I am trying to write code so that 18 LEDs will light up randomly except 2 of them light up together. Am I using `random` wrong? I initialized it to make the random number random.

Here is my code:

```c
int timer = 1000; 

int ranndom;  

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(30, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(31, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(32, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(33, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(34, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(35, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(36, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(37, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(38, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(39, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(40, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(41, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(42, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(43, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(44, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(45, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(46, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(47, OUTPUT); 

}


void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    ranndom = random(30, 47); 

    if (ranndom == 38 || ranndom == 39) { 
        digitalWrite(38, HIGH); 
        digitalWrite(39, HIGH); 
        delay(timer); 

        digitalWrite(38, LOW);
        digitalWrite(39, LOW); 
        delay(timer); 
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(ranndom, HIGH); 
        delay(timer); 

        digitalWrite(ranndom, LOW); 
        delay(timer); 
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with this code? Is it not working as you intended? If yes, please describe how it behaves and what you expected to do.

Comment: It just lights up the lights but does not turn them off. Is the code correct? like was random used correctly?

Comment: is the format correct? is the code used correctly?

Comment: pin 47 will not light up ever, because the maximum value parameter of `random()` is exclusive. And you might want to use `randomSeed()` to get real random numbers (the current way the number row will be equal for every power on of the device). The code itself seems good and should work.

Comment: So by changing random() to randomSeed(30,47) It will include 47 and get random numbers that associate with the pin the LED is connected to?

Comment: No, randomSeed has another functionality. Please read the documentation for it. And to get 47 into it, you need to specify a maximum value of 48.

Comment: when I change it, is it giving me the error of too many arguments. What do I need to change?

Comment: See here at the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/) that shows how to use `random()` and `randomSeed()`

Comment: I went back to random(30, 48) and then plugged it in and the lights are all going on at the same time and not even following the speed

Comment: Are you sure, that you uploaded the code correctly? And are the lights connected correctly? You can test with the blink example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. What type of Arduino do you use?

Comment: Please post the circuit you are using for the LEDs.

Comment: i am using relays. The type is a eledoo mega 2560

Comment: So It has started to slightly work for about 2 cylces and then it goes back to all the lights. I am the coder and not doing the circuit.

Comment: I redid the code and it works occasionally and then it stops working. here is the code:

Comment: int timer = 1000; 
long randNumber; 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  randomSeed(analogRead(30)); 
   
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  randNumber = random(30,48); 
  pinMode(randNumber,OUTPUT); 

  if (randNumber == 38 || randNumber == 39) { 
  digitalWrite(38, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(39, HIGH); 
  delay(timer); 

  digitalWrite(38, LOW);
  digitalWrite(39, LOW); 
 
  
}
else {
  digitalWrite(randNumber, HIGH); 
  delay(timer); 

  digitalWrite(randNumber, LOW); 
  
 
}

}

Comment: It would be best if you improved your question by editing your question to answer what people are asking here in the comments.

Comment: Since you are using relay: Do you have complete relay modules or do you connect just the relay directly to the Arduino? And how do you have them connected. This is important for the functionality of the code